# Laravel Former input field posted with empty value shows old (original) value instead of empty input field

Tags: laravel

I'm having some trouble using the Former plugin for Laravel, to handle forms & fields.

The use-case is an "edit"-form for a given model.

```
Former::text('title')
  ->label('Title')
  ->value( $title );

Former::text('description')
  ->label('Description')
  ->value( $description );
```

**Rules:**

- The title must always exist and be at least 10 chars long.
- The description may be empty.

**Expected behaviour:**

When loading the edit form, I expect the form to show the values of `$title` and `$description` in the fields.

Whenever submitting a the form with invalid field-values, I expect the submitted values to be shown in the fields, instead of the values of `$title` and `$description`.

**Problem:**

This works only when submitting non-empty strings!

When submitting an empty-string, it's like Former handles it like the field-hasn't even been submitted, and therefore uses the value given by `$title` or `$description` instead.

I thought Former was able to do this "smart", and take the `value($variable)` value only if the posted data does not contain the field. But it seems Former is taking the variables value also when the submitted was empty.

**Why is this a problem?**

Imagine you edit both fields, and actually want to change the `title` and remove the `description` entirely, which is valid according to the rules. Then, because you entered a too short `title`, the validation does not pass, and `title` will get the new (too short) `title` as field-value, while the `description` value will fall back to the value of the `$description` variable, instead of showing an empty field, which was posted.

It feels like `$_POST['description'] = ""` is treated like `$_POST['description'] = null` or is `not set` - even though the empty field is part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

In your view

```
//replace
Former::text('title')
->label('Title')
->value( $title );

//with
Former::text('title')
->label('Title')
```

... and in your controller

```
//add  
Former::populate($model);
```

$model beeing the model in question :)
$model->title must ofc exist and have the same value as $title in your original code.

if you use ->value($somevalue) with Former, $somevalue will allways be used.